# C++ compression (zip) library for closed-source app

Tags: c++, compression, zip

Please recommend a C++ compression (zip)  library for a commercial, closed-source application.  So, not a GPL license.

This is for my day job...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I know you said C++, but [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) is a very [permissively licensed](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_license.html) C library that you could use directly from a C++ app.

If I recall correctly, there are various "iostream-like" wrappers around zlib available, too.

Answer (score 11):

7 Zip is LGPL, meaning so long as you treat it like a 3rd-party library, your usage of it is fine in a closed-source app.

http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: From wikipedia: The LZMA SDK 4.62 was placed in the public domain in December 2008. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z

Answer (score 0):

If you need fast decompression, the best you can find is probably [LZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/). Be aware you need a separate (paid) commercial license when using in a closed source project. Still, if you need the fast decompression it may be well worth the money.

Answer (score 0):

[libbzip2](http://www.bzip.org/) is BSD-licensed and should [compress better, although slower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2#Compression_efficiency), than zlib.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://zziplib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

zip plugin within Ultimate IDE framework... It seems to be easy to use.
It uses zlib internally.